# Restore previous version of my comment on GitHub

Tags: github

I've added a comment to an issue report on GitHub. It was relatively significant with a lot of Markdown formatting in it.

Then I tried to make a minor edit in it, but due to the some bug of GitHub or Firefox, the contents of the comment got replaced with absolutely unrelated text (actually somehow it appears to be my another comment from another issue in the same repository — but it doesn't actually matter). I want to restore back the correct contents of the comment.

I see the “edited ▽” ([image: edited ▽]) button at the top of my comment. And pressing it reveals a list of versions of the comment where I can see the correct version. But the problem is that this feature allows me to **preview** previous version of my comment, but not to **restore** it. I mean:

- neither there is something like "Restore this comment version" button;
- neither I can delete the newest (invalid) version with the "Delete revision from history" button (because "The most recent revision cannot be deleted");
- neither I can copy the old contents to the clipboard and then paste it manually (because it just previews visual difference between two versions, but doesn't show full contents of a specific version with copyable Markdown formatting).

So it looks like "I **see** it, but I can't **get it** / **restore it**". Any ideas? Maybe there's a way to clone a special issue-tracker-repo (like I can download a special wiki-repo)? Maybe there's a way to get it through API?

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357280/print-commit-message-of-a-given-commit-in-git

Comment: @davidbaumann, sorry, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow managed to commit a cached version of my comment and found the same problem as you.

- in one tab, use the edited button to retrieve a good previous version, which displays in a frame. (The version of your text you pasted will be a diff - try to minimise the diff differences displayed as you'll need to manually edit them out)
- using your mouse, select all the content of that frame
- in Firefox right click and 'view selection source', or in Chrome you'll have to go to 'inspect' and find `<article class="markdown-body entry-content comment-body p-0"` and right click on that and select 'edit as HTML'. Select the resulting text
- in another tab, edit the issue comment and replace all text with the HTML
- edit the diff difference(s) in the text so your previous version is properly restored

If you want/need your text back in markdown format, convert it locally using pandoc or some other html>md conversion tool before you paste it back in the last step

Comment: But, even if I use some HTML-to-markdown converter (which probably won't restore the original formatting exactly), the “edited” button doesn't allow to **view the specific version of the comment exactly**. It displays **version diffs** (not _versions themselves_).

Comment: I accept this answer: (a) because GitHub probably doesn't provide a proper way to do it at all; (b) as a gesture of goodwill. But, to say truth, this is a thing that was obvious for me from the beginning and it doesn't satisfy my needs at all.

Comment: Thanks - yes I forgot to mention the necessity of diff-fixing, added into the steps